# How to change a sops encrypted secret without redeploy

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cronjob deployed.  I need to update a parameter -- rotate an AES key -- contained in the secret. The secret is sops encrypted.

Is it possible to update the AES key without redeploying the job?

What I have tried:

```
"kubectl edit secret jobsecret" -- edits the sops encrypted file but it is still encrypted
"helm edit secrets jobsecret.yaml" -- edits/encrypts the parameter file before deploy
```

My next thought is to create a file, then encrypt it with sops and copy/paste the result into the editor for "kubectl edit secret jobsecret".  I was hoping that there was a better way.

I am a developer, not a k8s admin. But, not by choice.  Filling in until we can remedy the "no k8s admin" issue.

Comment: Assuming that your aes_key is stored in `secret` in a `key`:`value` (value=aes_key) fashion you could try to use `$ kubectl patch secret YOUR_SECRET -p '{"data":{"aes_key":"NEW_BASE64_ENCODED_VALUE"}}'` Have you tried this way? Could you show the `YAML` definition of your `Job` and your `Secret`? Also please take a look on the official documentation about `Secret` that are mounted as `Volumes` (they are updated automatically): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#mounted-secrets-are-updated-automatically

Comment: PERFECT!!  Thank you!  "kubectl patch secret" is the answer.  I really appreciate it.  There was no arrow to upvote your comment.  If you want to put it in as an answer, I will be glad to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can use `$ kubectl patch` to update fields of resources.

Example:

```sh
kubectl patch secret YOUR_SECRET -p '{"data":{"key":"NEW_BASE64_ENCODED_VALUE"}}'
```

You can find more reference here:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Managed Kubernetes objects: Update api object kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)*

I've included more explanation below.

---

Example of "patching" a secret:

- `$ secret.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: super-secret
data:
  username: a3J1aw==
  password: b2xkLXBhc3N3b3Jk
```

> **A side note!**
>
> Values of keys like `username` and `password` are base64 encoded!

To change the value of `password` you will need to run:

- `kubectl patch super-secret  -p '{"data":{"password":"bmV3LXBhc3N3b3Jk"}}'`

Displaying the newly updated secret should show (the output is only partial):

- `$ kubectl get secret super-secret -o yaml`

```
data:
  password: bmV3LXBhc3N3b3Jk 
  username: a3J1aw==
```

---

I highly encourage you to check the additional reference:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Configuration: Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)*
- *[Itnext.io: How to automatically update your Kubernetes app configuration](https://itnext.io/how-to-automatically-update-your-kubernetes-app-configuration-d750e0ca79ab)*